# How can I run SQL Plus on Ubuntu 18.04 server, after I've installed Oracle 19c on it using Docker?

Tags: oracle, docker, ubuntu-18.04

- I've installed Oracle 19c on Ubuntu 18.04 server, using Docker.
- I can connect to the installed DB, using SQL developer & Dbeaver, and am working with it fine.
- But I can't run SqlPlus, or restore Dump backup file on it.

  sudo docker exec -ti oracle19c sqlplus /as sysdba
- Could anyone help me pl?

[ORA-12162 & ORA-12154 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI6qa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with my 18cXE image (container_name: oracle). I think you have to make sure environment is set before you issue `sqlplus / as sysdba`

```
docker container exec -it oracle su oracle -c ". oraenv <<< XE; sqlplus / as sysdba"
ORACLE_SID = [XE] ? The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Feb 3 22:44:10 2021
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> select instance_name from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NAME
----------------
XE

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is not supported on Ubuntu, period. It is written for an entirely different branch of Linux. If your container is running RHEL or Oracle Linux then things might work within that context, but it will not run (or will not run reliably, in a supported fashion, even if you hack it in) on the Ubuntu kernel. You will need a Red Hat or Red Hat compatible kernel if you want either the client or the server to run as intended.